# Find first non-matching line in VIM

Tags: search, vim

It happens sometimes that I have to look into various log and trace files on Windows and generally I use for the purpose VIM.

My problem though is that I still can't find any *analog* of `grep -v` inside of VIM: find in the buffer a line **not** matching given regular expression. E.g. log file is filled with lines which somewhere in a middle contain phrase `all is ok` and I need to find first line which doesn't contain `all is ok`.

I can write a custom function for that, yet at the moment that seems to be an overkill and likely to be slower than a native solution.

Is there any easy way to do it in VIM?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use negative look-behind operator `@<!`

e.g. to find all lines not containing "a", use `/\v^.+(^.*a.*$)@<!$`

(`\v` just causes some operators like `(` and `@<!` not to must have been backslash escaped)

the simpler method is to delete all lines matching or not matching the pattern (`:g/PATTERN/d` or `:g!/PATTERN/d` respectively)

Comment: `/^.\+\(^.*all is ok.*$\)\@<!$` works as desired - thanks a bunch!

Comment: `:g!/PATTERN/p` produces too much output. for a few mln line file that isn't an option. but `:g!/PATTERN/d` looks very useful e.g. for working with buffer read from stdin, not saved to a file yet.

Comment: Uhm... obviously the `:g!/PATTERN/d` for my case (ignore the uninteresting lines macthing PATTER) should be written as `:g/PATTERN/d` - without ! - to remove the uninteresting lines.

Comment: Nice solution! I don't think you need ^ and I like "verymagic", so I prefer this for readability: /\v(all is ok.*)@<!$

Comment: This works, but it is very slow. I think it is more efficient to use `/\v^((.*all is ok.*)@!.)*$` as documented on the vim [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_lines_not_containing_pattern_and_other_helpful_searches).

Comment: I found that `/\v^(.*pattern)@!/` seemed to do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 26):

I believe if you simply want to have your cursor end up at the first non-matching line you can use visual as the command in your global command.  So:

```
:v/pattern/visual
```

will leave your cursor at the first non-matching line.  Or:

```
:g/pattern/visual
```

will leave your cursor at the first matching line.

Comment: the visual command can also be shortened to vi... so you can do :v/pattern/vi

Comment: It finds the first non-matching line starting from the beginning of the file, but not starting from the current cursor position. Use `:.,$v/pattern/vi` for searching from the cursor position.

Comment: Denilson: You should submit yours as an answer

Answer (score 10):

It's probably already too late, but I think that this should be said somewhere.

Vim (since version about 7.4) comes with a plugin called **LogiPat**, which makes searching for lines which don't contain some string really easy. So using this plugin finding the lines not containing `all is ok` is done like this:

```
:LogiPat !"all is ok"
```

And then you can jump between the matching (or in this case not matching) lines with `n` and `N`.

You can also use logical operations like `&` and `|` to join different strings in one pattern:

```
:LP !("foo"|"bar")&"baz"
```

`LP` is shorthand for `LogiPat`, and this command will search for lines that contain the word `baz` and don't contain neither `foo` nor `bar`.

Comment: LogiPat is really cool, but in some cases the regex it generates can be much slower than what you'd write by hand. For example, if I want to find lines without "a", "b", and "c", `/\v^(.*(a|b|c))@!` is much faster than `:LogiPat !"a"&!"b"&!"c"`, which generates `\%(^\%(\%(a\)\@!.\)*$\&\%(^\%(\%(b\)\@!.\)*$\&^\%(\%(c\)\@!.\)*$\)\)`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm often in your case, so to "clean" the logs files I use :

```
:g/all is ok/d
```

Your `grep -v` can be achieved with

```
:v/error/d
```

Which will remove all lines which does **not** contain *error*.

Answer (score 3):

I just managed a somewhat klutzy procedure using the "g" command:

```
:%g!/search/p
```

This says to print out the non-matching lines... not sure if that worked, but it did end up with the cursor positioned on the first non-matching line.

(substitute some other string for "search", of course)

Comment: @Jefromi: Thanks for that, I'd forgotten about `:v`.

Answer (score 3):

You can search with following line and press n to jump to the first non-matching line

```
^\(.*all is ok\)\@!.*$
```

Breakdown of operators:

```
^           -> means start of the line
\( and \)   -> To match a whole string multiple times, it must be grouped into one item. This is done by putting "\(" before it and "\)" after it.
\@!         -> Matches with zero width if the preceding atom does NOT match at the current position.
.*          -> Matches any character repeated 1 or more times
$           -> end of the line
```

Here is sample animation how it works. For simplicity I searched for word apple.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the non-matches using g and a null substitution:

```
:g!/pattern/s/^//c
```

If you reply "n" each time you wont even mark the file as changed.

You need ctrl-C to escape from the circle (or keep going to bottom of file).